# How save globally catched exceptions in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am building a web application where I will have a lot of controllers with their corresponding action methods in them.

I want to save every exception in database and for this reason I have created 
ExceptionService (DbContext is injected in it).

let's say that this is the general form of my controllers:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager userManager;
    private readonly IExceptionService exceptionService;

    public UserController(UserManager userManager, IExceptionService exceptionService)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.exceptionService = exceptionService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] User user)
    {

        try
        {
            //some code
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exceptionService.Save(e);
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

In order to avoid so many try-catch blocks I decided to create a filter which looks like this:

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IExceptionService exceptionService;

    public ApiExceptionFilterAttribute(IExceptionService exceptionService)
    {
        this.exceptionService = exceptionService;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        Exception e = context.Exception;
        exceptionService.Save(e);

        //some code
    }
}
```

Code in ConfigureServices method in StartUp.cs looks like this (some code  removed for simplicity):

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

services
   .AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

services.AddScoped<UserManager>();
services.AddScoped<SignInManager>();


services.AddScoped<IExceptionService, ExceptionService>();


services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, ConfigureMvcOptions>();
```

ConfgureMvcOptions class looks like this:

```
public class ConfigureMvcOptions : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    private readonly IExceptionService exceptionService;

    public ConfigureMvcOptions(IExceptionService exceptionService)
    {
        this.exceptionService = exceptionService;
    }

    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilterAttribute(exceptionService));
    }
}
```

When I run this application, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot consume scoped service 'SmartWay.Services.IExceptionService' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions]'.'
```

If I change IExceptionServcise's lifetime to transient than I have to do so for 
Dbcontext, then for DbContextOptions... It seems that it isn't right way..

So, How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You're essentially reinventing [Elmah](https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore), just so you're aware

Comment: What will you do if the exception occurs due to failing to connect to the database?

Comment: @mjwills I think I will catch it and do nothing with it, or I will save it in textfile

Comment: @AlexanderMujirishvili you are mixing cross-cutting concerns *IMO*. Rethink the current design choices.

Comment: Probably it will be better to save all exceptions in files, what do you think?

Comment: Why is IConfigure options is a service??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolving scoped service from singleton service, try `_serviceProvider.CreateScope`.

Follow steps below:

1. `ExceptionService`

   ```
   public interface IExceptionService
   {
       void Save(Exception ex);
   }

   public class ExceptionService : IExceptionService
   {
       private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
       public ExceptionService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
       {
           _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
       }
       public void Save(Exception ex)
       {
           using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
           {
               var _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MVCProContext>();
               _context.Add(new Book() { Title = ex.Message });
               _context.SaveChanges();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. `Startup.cs`

   ```
   services.AddSingleton<IExceptionService, ExceptionService>();
   services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, ConfigureMvcOptions>();
   ```